# How to test NFC Tag interaction in Android since android.nfc.Tag cannot be instatiated?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, unit-testing, nfc

I am currently working on an Android application that involves NFC tags. In my app, I need to write to NFC tags, and I would like to write some unit tests that directly interact with the [`android.nfc.Tag`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/Tag) class. The following method is an example of the functionality I need to test:

```kotlin
    fun write(tag: Tag, message: NdefMessage) {
        val ndef = Ndef.get(tag) ?: throw Exception()
        ndef.connect()
        ndef.writeNdefMessage(message)
        ndef.close()
    }
```

Is there a way to instantiate the `Tag` class in unit tests?

The constructor of the `Tag` class is hidden, making it impossible to instantiate it outside the `android.nfc` package. Additionally, it's not extensible because the Tag class is marked as final. With Android SDK 34, it's also not possible to use reflection. I attempted the solution mentioned in this StackOverflow thread ([How to mock a Android NFC Tag object for unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841803/how-to-mock-a-android-nfc-tag-object-for-unit-testing)), but I encountered the error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.nfc.Tag.createMockTag`. It seems that the Android team has restricted access to that method for privacy reasons. I've also tried the way suggested in [Testing an app by faking NFC tag scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882171/testing-an-app-by-faking-nfc-tag-scan) but without success for my use case because the Tag is not well formed.

My last option is to mock it using [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) or another mocking library, but I am hesitant to do so because it would mean testing with a mocked implementation rather than the actual one.

Comment: There are not really many other options, other than manual testing with a real device, this is what I do. As most of the testing needed is for how to correctly handle Exceptions and timing issues generated quite often by user behaviour.